# How to programmatically show user location on a MKMapView iOS?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, uiactionsheet

I'm trying to make a app that has a MKMapView, and you can turn on/off whether it shows your location or not. I'm using a UIActionSheet to let the user decide to turn it showsUserLocation on/off. The problem is not the UIActionSheet, but that I can't seem to get the MKMapView to display the user location when I select the YES option.

Code in the `- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` Method:

```
// Show User Location ActionSheet
if (actionSheet.tag == 1) {

    // YES Button
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        MapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

    }

    // NO Button
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        MapView.showsUserLocation = NO;

    }

}
```

It's not showing the User's Location, even though I press the YES button. Help please?!?!

Comment: `.showUserLocation` doesn't show the user location. Its a property of the `MKMapView` object. If it is set to NO then the user's location isn't shown on the map. Try using the `didUpdateLocation` method to get the coordinate and then use that in your `MKMapView`

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:

Comment: Are you trying to move the map to where the user is, or draw the blue dot where the user is (which may not be on the screen at the moment) or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, I found a video that helped me a lot!

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTDXzYzIhVI

This tutorial on YouTube helped me display the user's location on the MKMapView. Turns out that in the `- (void)viewDidLoad` Method, I needed to add `[MapView setDelegate:self];`. Boy, that was a stupid mistake! :P

Answer (score 0):

showsUserLocation tells the map to enable the user location blue dot, but it does not scroll the map to the user's location.

To do that you'll need to ask for location updates and change the map region with the information you get.

Alternately I seem to remember that you can use KVO to observe the map's userLocation property.